# TextView doesn't show the required text

Tags: java, android, textview, android-viewgroup

My `MainActivity` class has an if that checks is something is true it starts a new `Activity` which sets the text of a `TextView` to what I want.

`MainActivity`:

```
 public static int caseA = 1;

 if(caseA) {
     Intent i = new Intent(Timer.this, WorkTimerNotification.class);
     startActivity(i);
 }
```

then it goes to the new `Activity` and it should check the value of `caseA`.

`WorkTimerNotification`:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_work_timer_notification);
    TextView timerMetric = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tester_texter);
    if(MainActivity.caseA) {
            timerMetric.setText("min");
        }
```

Problem: It does not change the text. Also, lets say I have many other if statements in mainactivity like:

```
 if(caseB) {}
 if(caseC) {}
 //and so on..
```

How would I perform the checks? More importantly, how do I get this caseA check to work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `findViewById()` in `onCreate()`:

```
private TextView timerMetric;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_work_timer_notification);

    timerMetric = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tester_texter);

    if(caseA) {
        timerMetric.setText("min");
    }
}
```

Right now you are calling it before calling `setContentView()`, before the view hierarchy is generated. For this reason, your code fails.

Comment: private TextView timerMetric is an unused variable. Why call it like that?

Comment: how is it *unused* ?? aren't you using it in onCreate() ?